# Handling OnAction Event of a button in a custom cell of a listview in javafx

Tags: listview, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am new to JavaFX.
I tried an application where i have a custom cell listview. In a list view cell, i have a HBox containing 4 labels, 1 imageview and 2 buttons. I created a cell using scenebuilder. I am not able to handle OnAction Event of any of the buttons. Can you please check my code and suggest how to do this? all the labels and the imageview is working fine.

1. my List View is declared in a MainSCeneController

```
public class MainSceneController implements Initializable {

    @FXML public ListView<model.Post> listView = new ListView<>();;
    ObservableList <model.Post> StudentObservablelist;
     public void LoadDataButtonPushed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

                StudentObservablelist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i < Uni_Link.All_posts.size(); i++) {
                    StudentObservablelist.add(Uni_Link.All_posts.get(i));
                }
                listView.setItems(StudentObservablelist);
                listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Post>, ListCell<Post>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ListCell<Post> call(ListView<Post> studentListView) {
                        return new StudentListViewCell();
                    }
                });

    }
```

2. The list View Cell looks like this:

```
public class StudentListViewCell extends ListCell<Post> {
    @FXML private HBox hMain /*, hButton*/;
    //@FXML private VBox V1, V2, V3, V4;
    @FXML private ImageView image = new ImageView();
    @FXML private Label label1  = new Label();
    @FXML private Label label2 = new Label() ;
    @FXML private Label label3 = new Label();
    @FXML private Label label4 = new Label();
    @FXML private Label label5 = new Label();
    @FXML private Label label6 = new Label();
    @FXML private Button reply = new Button("Reply") ;
    @FXML private Button more_details = new Button("More Details") ;

    FXMLLoader loader;

    public StudentListViewCell(){
        super();
    }

    protected void updateItem(Post post, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(post, empty);

        setText(null);  // No text in label of super class
        if (empty){
            setGraphic(null);
        }
        else {
            if(loader == null) {
                   try {
                          loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/ListViewCell.fxml"));
                          loader.setController(this);
                          loader.load();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                   }   
            }
            label1.setText("Title: "+post.getTitle());
            label2.setText("Status: "+post.getStatus());
            label3.setText("Creator: "+post.getCreator_ID());
            String photo = post.getPhoto();
            image.setImage(new Image("/Images/"+photo));
            setGraphic(hMain);
```

Where, ListViewCell.fxml file is created using Scenebuilder. and looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<HBox fx:id="hMain" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="110.0" prefWidth="691.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <VBox fx:id="V3" prefHeight="110.0" prefWidth="130.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="image" fitHeight="110.0" fitWidth="144.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <VBox fx:id="V1" alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="110.0" prefWidth="117.0" spacing="20.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="label1" text=" " />
            <Label fx:id="label2" text=" " />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets top="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </VBox>
      <VBox fx:id="V2" alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="149.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="110.0" prefWidth="131.0" spacing="20.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="label3" text=" " />
            <Label fx:id="label4" text=" " />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets top="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </VBox>
      <VBox fx:id="V4" alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="110.0" prefWidth="125.0" spacing="20.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="label5" text=" " />
            <Label fx:id="label6" prefHeight="19.0" prefWidth="116.0" text=" " />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets top="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </VBox>
      <HBox fx:id="hButton" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="110.0" prefWidth="180.0" spacing="20.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="reply" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#replyButtonPushed" text="Reply" />
            <Button fx:id="more_details" mnemonicParsing="false" text="More Details" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets left="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

I have to handle replyButtonPushed method which is onAction method of a reply button for each Post cell in a listview.

Comment: Writing OnAction event handler in the Cell constructor is not working

Comment: 1. Never initialize fields annotated `@FXML`. 2. You haven’t defined the `replyButtonPushed()` method referenced in the FXML file.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Comment: fields having the same name as the id in the fxml are injected via reflection by java fx.